# Executing MSYS2 Emacs from Windows command line or shortcut

Tags: bash, mingw-w64, msys2

I recently installed MSYS2 with Emacs (64-bit) and am currently calling that Emacs from a Windows shortcut. It works fine, exactly like if I had downloaded the Emacs executable for Windows and unzipped it somewhere. Which is to say, it picks up all of my Windows environment variables and such.

For various reasons, I would prefer to run Emacs from an MSYS2 bash shell and use the environment variables in that shell. As it stands, I can open an MSYS2 MINGW64 shell, type `emacs` on the command line, and everything works the way I want it to.

Now I would like to package the whole thing up into either a one-liner I can stuff into to a Windows shortcut or a script I can call from a Windows shortcut. With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438779/executing-a-script-in-msys2-mingw), I came up with the following:

```
C:\msys64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -l -c /mingw64/bin/emacs
```

This successfully opens Emacs, but fails to load the `.bashrc` file that I source in `.bash_profile` in the usual manner:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

I define a function in `.bashrc` that I call in `.bash_profile`, so this is kind of important. It did not take much effort to realize that the problem is that `HOME` is not defined, so `.bashrc` is simply not found. However, if I define `HOME` like so:

```
C:\msys64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env HOME=/home/alanhr MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -l -c /mingw64/bin/emacs
```

I get exactly the same result: `.bashrc` is not found and my function is not executed. Here's where it gets weird. If I simply leave off the call to `emacs` like so:

```
C:\msys64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env HOME=/home/alanhr MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -l
```

I get a bash shell where `.bashrc` has been loaded correctly and my function is correctly executed. I can type `emacs` on the command line and have it function exactly as I want it to.

This feels like a classic case of missing something that is right under my nose, but I have read the `bash` man page to no avail. Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2):

It is the [`-i`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) option to load `.bashrc`. The following works for me:

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe -w hide /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -l -i -c /mingw64/bin/emacs
```

Comment: Thanks for that -- as I suspected, something simple I was missing. Unfortunately, in the time since I posted my question I've gone back to using a natively compiled Windows version of Emacs. I miss MSYS2, though, so I might go back and give this a try.